# TNS Listener started but not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, listener

My listener exists and is started, but when I try to connect to the database it tells me no listener exists.  I've tried restarting the listener to no effect.

#### listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (PROGRAM = CLRExtProc)
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.164)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\Oracle
```

#### tsnames.ora

```
EPABFM =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.164)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = epabfm)
    )
  )

LISTENER_EPABFM =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.164)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Result of lsnrctl status:

```
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 19-SEP-2015 14:59:14

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.164)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                19-SEP-2015 14:58:11
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 1 min. 5 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\firexion-main\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.164)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 3 handler(s) for this service...
Service "epabfm" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "epabfm", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "epabfmXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "epabfm", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: from what server do you connect, how do you connect and what is the error message?

Comment: Everything is local to my machine; I connect to it either through sql developer or when starting up my jboss server.  
The error was something like, no TNS listener found.  I can't replicate it now because I ended up completely removing Oracle from my machine and reinstalling it and the database which fixed the issue.